# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' - unable to connect to database using java application

Tags: java, mysql

I  am using ubuntu as my base image in docker and I have installed mysql 5.7 and I am able to connect to test database from command line by providing the credentials.

```
root@test:/tmp/test# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

root@test:/tmp/test# mysql -uroot -proot
    mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 22
    Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

    Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.

    Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

    mysql> exit
    Bye
```

However I am  having issues when I am trying to run simple java application that connects to test database.Heres my code.

```
import java.sql.*;
class test{
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
while(rs.next())
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));
con.close();
}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
}
}
```

Issue:

```
root@test:/tmp/test# java -cp "./mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar:/tmp/test" test
Wed Dec 19 22:00:05 GMT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: By default users can only connect to MySQL from the local server. Did you grant remote access to the user "root"?

Comment: yes i issued the command GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'; and restarted mysql but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the network listener. To listen on all network interfaces (open it to all networks), you can:

1. Set the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`. To do this, edit the `my.cnf` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
   ```

   in it make sure the bind-address is uncommented (no `#` at the line beginning) and set as:

   ```
   bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
   ```
2. Save the file, and then restart the MySQL server process:

   sudo service mysql restart
3. Alternatively, you can restart the whole server.

Comment: i couldnt find  bind-address in my.cnf

Comment: It only has the following:
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/